# Count with criteria for changing column in excel

Tags: excel

I have a data looks like this:

a  b  c
1  3  4
2  3  3
4  1  2
2  4  2

In another worksheet, I want to do the following calculation:
whenever A1 returns a (header of data worksheet), count number of items that are smaller and equal to 2 in column "a". (result will be 2)
if A1 returns b, count number of items that are smaller and equal to 2 in column "b". (result will be 1).
A1 has already been preset with formula such that it will show a or b or c as conditions changed.

I need the formula to be lean... I actually have 6 headers, so if I keep on using if functions, I will probably have to set 6 if functions in one cell...that can be overwhelming.  index match cannot provide a range to work on...Any suggestion? thanks

I don't know vba. If you could provide a workable vba code, i don't mind. but i don't know how to read it...>.< please provide user manual for that. lol, thank you~

Answer (score 0):

If your data sheet is Sheet1, you could try the array formula:-

```
=SUM((Sheet1!A1:C1=$A$1)*(Sheet1!A2:C5<=2))
```

Must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

(actually there are 3 items less than or equal to 2 in column A)

Or you can use the SUMPRODUCT version if you prefer not to use an array formula:-

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!A1:C1=$A$1)*(Sheet1!A2:C5<=2))
```

Or you can use this INDEX/MATCH method which is probably more efficient:-

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(Sheet1!A2:C5,,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A1:C1,0)),"<="&2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is found on Sheet1 and the a is found on column a, b is found on column b etc. enter this formula on then next sheet on  b1 when a1 is the column value:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&a1&":"&a1),"<=2")
```

The `Indirect` is for adding text to your reference.